Wrapping literal string values in single quotes to pass to SQL
Building a SQL Query to pass along.
I have something like this:
enum LogEntryType
{
    IsUpdate,
    IsInsert,
    IsDelete
}
//
//
//
string thingsToSelect = "*";
var source = LogEntryType.IsDelete;

string myQuery = source switch
{
    LogEntryType.IsInsert => "SELECT * FROM Table1;",
    LogEntryType.IsDelete or LogEntryType.IsUpdate =>
        $@"SELECT {thingsToSelect} FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ActionType = 'Deleted' ",
   _ => throw new NotImplementedException(),
    
};

Notice that 'Deleted' is in single quotes because I want to pass it to SQL like this:
SELECT * FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ActionType = 'Deleted' 

However I want that 'Deleted' part to be more dynamic such that if the switch is using LogEntryType.IsDelete then it should be 'Deleted' and when switch is LogEntryType.IsUpdate it should be 'Updated' so one of these two as final statement for those two switch statements.
SELECT * FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ActionType = 'Deleted' 
SELECT * FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ActionType = 'Updated'

But I had trouble embedding this logic that can also wrap it around single quoutes in a one liner in that switch statement. That's what I need help with please.

Why must it be the same switch branch? Why not split the 'or' in two cases which would - admittedly - introduce some level of duplication but in the same instant solve your problem in a very readable way?

Are you just looking to embed {LogEntryType.IsDelete ? "Deleted" : "Updated"} in the string?  It's not really clear to me where you're stuck.

@David yes exactly . And I had done what you have but in the final result it will not have it wrapped around singe quotes sadly

@Fildor  yep originally had it like that but my "real" sql is much longer. this is just a short version for posting here. So I did not want to duplicate the code just for one line of code difference

@Bohn: If that's what you're trying to do then what have you tried?  What prevents your string from containing single quotes?

=> Erm like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/cct5UJ

@Fildor yep but now we need to replace your line number 8 with the enum comparison.

... or lookup: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJe20p

The point of my first example being, that you were probably missing the () inside the {} in your failed attempts?

cool, I just did it using your first example.  We could just do enum comparison inside. It worked. So no dictionary or mapper needed.  Thanks for help with syntax

... ExtensionMethod => https://dotnetfiddle.net/gcHI1y

You can use ternary operator, or by clipping the enum name, but I tend to write them seperately.
$@"SELECT {thingsToSelect} FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ActionType = '{(source == LogEntryType.IsDelete ? "Delete" : "Update")}' "
$@"SELECT {thingsToSelect} FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ActionType = '{source.ToString().Substring(2)}' "


I don't want to play with values of my enum names like that.  Also imagine the values to match on are 'Hello'  and 'GoodBye'

Create map function:
string Map(LogEntryType logEntryType){
 switch(logEntryType)
 {
  case LogEntryType.IsUpdate: return "Updated";
  ...
 }
}

Use it like this:
    $@"SELECT {thingsToSelect} FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ActionType = '{Map(source)}' ",


haa? what ? .....

bro you serious? what is not clear?

You can do the same with a Dictionary<LogEntryType, string> ...

@Fildor, sure you can, there are a lot of options. Most important here that you need to map the enum to string.
